# Google charts com php

Tags: php, google-charts

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde cada usuário vai receber diferentes tipos diferentes de dados através do google charts, no entanto não consigo fazer com que os dados apareçam na tela. Segue o trecho do código javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                [{label: 'Status', type: 'string'},
                 {label: 'Quantidade', type: 'number'}
                ],

                <?php
                    foreach ($_SESSION["data_grafico1"] as $dados){
                        echo "['$dados[0]', $dados[1]]";
                    }
                ?>
                ]);



            // Set chart options
            var options = {'title':'Quantidade de protocolos por Status',
                'width':400,
                'height':300};

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
```

As informações contidas em na variável $dados são os índices (string), representados por $dados[0] e os valores numéricos contidos em $dados[1] respectivamente. Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão? 
As informações em $dados[0] e $dados[1] são recuperadas normalmente, no entanto ao adicionar no js não são exibidas. Agradeço a ajuda de antemão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário criar um `array` com os dados do `foreach` mas a key `0` precisa ser o titulo dos eixos.

> `$array_list[]="['Status','Quantidade']";` //setando o titulo do eixo

Agora crie o `foreach` e alimente o `array_list` com os dados

```
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION["data_grafico1"] as $dados){
    $array_list[]= "['$dados[0]', $dados[1]]";
}
?>
```

Criado o `$array` agora basta inseri-lo no gráfico.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      <?php echo (implode(",", $array_list)); ?> //inserindo o array_list
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Quantidade de protocolos por Status'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Dessa forma o gráfico será criado dentro da `div` com o `id` definido dentro do `JS`

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta, deu certinho aqui.

Comment: Que bom poder ajudar, se a resposta atendeu sua necessidade peço que finalize a mesma